# Mariadb can't be installed on Debian Buster, : post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134

Tags: mysql, mariadb, apt, debian-buster

I am trying to install Mariadb on Debian but I am getting the error below when I try to install it.

Mariadb was actually working for me for a while. I just tried to reinstall it because it was having hard time with starting (probably broke after `apt upgrade`). So I removed it and tried to reinstall it.

`4.19.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.16-1 (2019-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.12-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.3.postinst: line 25:  9411 Done                    echo "$password_column_fix_query"
      9412 Aborted                 | $MYSQL_BOOTSTRAP 2>&1
      9416                       | $ERR_LOGGER
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.3 (--configure):
 installed mariadb-server-10.3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-test:
 mariadb-test depends on mariadb-server-10.3 (= 1:10.3.12-2); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-test (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.3
 mariadb-test
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.12-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mariadb-server-10.3.postinst: line 25:  9683 Done                    echo "$password_column_fix_query"
      9684 Aborted                 | $MYSQL_BOOTSTRAP 2>&1
      9685                       | $ERR_LOGGER
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.3 (--configure):
 installed mariadb-server-10.3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-test:
 mariadb-test depends on mariadb-server-10.3 (= 1:10.3.12-2); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-test (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.3
 mariadb-test
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Something like `dpkg --audit`, `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt -f install`? Maybe purging the package by doing `apt remove --purge mariadb-server` and then reboot and reinstall could help.

Comment: Hi I actually reverted back to previous version of MariaDB and it worked. I think the upgrade was borked.

Comment: if you are upgrading major version then first you need to remove first.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you didn't remove mysql completely before trying to use mariadb or in your case you did not remove the mariadb package completely So try this.

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt remove --purge mysql
sudo apt remove --purge mariadb
sudo apt remove --purge mariadb*
sudo apt --purge remove mariadb-server
```

Then try re installing it again

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```